# how to use connect by method dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by, subquery

How to achieve the following

I've got a query:

```
select sr.source_rel_id,
       sr.source_rel_start,
       sr.source_rel_end,
       sr.source_rel_end-sr.source_rel_start+ 1 as daycount
 from (SELECT RELEASES.REL_ID as source_rel_id,
              RELEASES.REL_START_DATE as source_rel_start,
              RELEASES.REL_END_DATE as source_rel_end
         FROM RELEASES) sr
```

which delivers this result:

[image]

I'm trying to create an additionally coloumn (based on the attached screenshot) filled with incrementally rising dates between the given start and end interval.

Here's what I want to accomplish:

[image]

The number on the right side shows how many records should be generated for each IDs.

Sorry for my poor english, I hope it's understandable.

Comment: Please post your data and results [as formatted text rather than images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a connect-by query that generates rows, for example to generate rows from 1 to 10 use:

```
select level as x
from dual connect by level <= 10;

|  X |
|----|
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
```

in order to generate rows from 5 to 10 use:

```
select 5 + level - 1 as x
from dual connect by level <= 10 - 5 + 1;

|  X |
|----|
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
```

In order to generate dates from `2017-01-02` to `2017-01-05` use:

```
select date '2017-01-02' + level - 1 as x
from dual connect by level <= date '2017-01-05' - date '2017-01-02' + 1;

|                    X |
|----------------------|
| 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-01-03T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-01-04T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-01-05T00:00:00Z |
```

---

If you are using Oracle 12c then you can use LATERAL or CROSSAPPLY to run the latter generator query form many start+end values coming from source subquery or table, please consider the following example:

```
create table probe(
   source_rel_id int,
   source_rel_start date,
   source_rel_end date
);

insert into probe values( 1, date '2017-01-02', date '2017-01-05' );
insert into probe values( 2, date '2017-03-01', date '2017-03-15' );
insert into probe values( 3, date '2017-05-05', date '2017-05-30' );
commit;
```

---

```
select * from probe p
cross apply (
    select p.source_rel_start + level - 1 as my_date
    from dual connect by level <= p.source_rel_end - p.source_rel_start + 1
)

SOURCE_REL_ID SOURCE_REL_START SOURCE_REL_END   MY_DATE         
------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
            1 2017/01/02 00:00 2017/01/05 00:00 2017/01/02 00:00
            1 2017/01/02 00:00 2017/01/05 00:00 2017/01/03 00:00
            1 2017/01/02 00:00 2017/01/05 00:00 2017/01/04 00:00
            1 2017/01/02 00:00 2017/01/05 00:00 2017/01/05 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/01 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/02 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/03 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/04 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/05 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/06 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/07 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/08 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/09 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/10 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/11 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/12 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/13 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/14 00:00
            2 2017/03/01 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00 2017/03/15 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/05 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/06 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/07 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/08 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/09 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/10 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/11 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/12 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/13 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/14 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/15 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/16 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/17 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/18 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/19 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/20 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/21 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/22 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/23 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/24 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/25 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/26 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/27 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/28 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/29 00:00
            3 2017/05/05 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00 2017/05/30 00:00
```

---

**EDIT**

---

> What other options I've got, if I'm not having 12c? I should check the
>   version but I remember for 11.

Just generate a series of numbers from 1 to N, where N must be greater than the highest count of numbers you want to generate for one record, in this way:

```
  SELECT level as xyz FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10000
```

and then join a result of the above query to the table in this way --> please see [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a7ace4/4)

```
SELECT source_rel_id, source_rel_start, source_rel_end,
       source_rel_start + xyz - 1 As days
FROM (
  SELECT level as xyz FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10000
) x
JOIN probe p
ON xyz <= source_rel_end - source_rel_start + 1
ORDER BY source_rel_id, days

| SOURCE_REL_ID |     SOURCE_REL_START |       SOURCE_REL_END |                 DAYS |
|---------------|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|             1 | 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z |
|             1 | 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-03T00:00:00Z |
|             1 | 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-04T00:00:00Z |
|             1 | 2017-01-02T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-01-05T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-02T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-03T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-04T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-05T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-06T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-07T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-08T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-09T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-10T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-11T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-12T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-13T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-14T00:00:00Z |
|             2 | 2017-03-01T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z | 2017-03-15T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-06T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-07T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-08T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-09T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-10T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-11T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-12T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-13T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-14T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-15T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-16T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-17T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-18T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-19T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-20T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-21T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-22T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-23T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-24T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-25T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-26T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-27T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-28T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-29T00:00:00Z |
|             3 | 2017-05-05T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z | 2017-05-30T00:00:00Z |
```

I've used 10000, it should be enough since 10000 days is over 27 years, so I don't think you need to generate 27 years of dates for each record, but if this is still too little, then in practice it can be a number somwhere between 1 million and 10 millions. Since rows are generated in the memory, at some point ( 1~10 millions) you will hit an out of memory error.
You can also use a subquery to calculate this limit exactly:

```
SELECT level as xyz FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (
     SELECT max(  source_rel_end - source_rel_start ) + 1
     FROM probe
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer krokodilko.

Comment: I'll give it a try today evening. What other options I've got, if I'm not having 12c? I should check the version but I remember for 11.

Comment: I've added an example how to do it in erlier versions of Oracle

Comment: I owe you a beer. Many thanks. I've got Oracle 12c, so your solution with using cross apply worked well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still on Oracle 11g (suggested in a comment), you can do this with a `connect by` hierarchical query, but because you're getting the data from multiple source rows you need include a reference to a non-deterministic function (I've used `dbms_random.value but others are available...) to prevent that:

```
select rel_id as source_rel_id,
  rel_start_date + level - 1 as days,
  rel_end_date - rel_start_date + 1 as daycount
from releases
connect by rel_id  = prior rel_id
and prior dbms_random.value is not null
and level <= rel_end_date - rel_start_date + 1;
```

which gets, using just the first three rows of your sample data, 92 rows in the result set:

```
SOURCE_REL_ID DAYS         DAYCOUNT
------------- ---------- ----------
           68 2016-03-01         31
           68 2016-03-02         31
           68 2016-03-03         31
...
           68 2016-03-30         31
           68 2016-03-31         31
           71 2016-06-01         30
           71 2016-06-02         30
...
           71 2016-06-29         30
           71 2016-06-30         30
           73 2016-08-01         31
           73 2016-08-02         31
...
           73 2016-08-30         31
           73 2016-08-31         31
```

If you're on 11gR2 (or higher) you can also do this with [recursive subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG) a.k.a a recursive CTE:

```
with rcte (source_rel_id, rel_end_date, days, daycount) as (
  select rel_id, rel_end_date, rel_start_date, rel_end_date - rel_start_date + 1
  from releases
  union all
  select source_rel_id, rel_end_date, days + 1, daycount
  from rcte
  where days < rel_end_date
)
select source_rel_id, days, daycount
from rcte
order by source_rel_id, days;
```

which gets the same result - other than being ordered explicitly, which probably isn't a bad thing.

The anchor branch of the CTE gets data from your base table and adds two extra columns: `daycount` which is calculated as before, and `days` which is the same as the start date for this first set of rows. The `rel_end_date` needs to be available to the recursive branch so that is included, but `rel_start_date` can be skipped.

The recursive branch then adds one day to `days` until it reaches the end date. If the `days` value from the previous generated row is already `rel_end_date` then the condition is not met so it stops, for that source row.

Finally you query only the columns you want to see from the CTE - in this case, just excluding the `rel_end_date` that was passed through to provide the stop condition, but which you don't actually want to see.